# How to code in Laravel so that the requests are executed without refreshing the page?

Tags: laravel, forms, request, refresh

In Laravel when we using forms to store or delete a resource, the page is refreshed. What is the best technology to avoid refreshing the page while the request is being processed? AJAX, Vue.js, etc?

Comment: AJAX, Vue.js, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main ways to handle http requests: synchronously and asynchronously.

Laravel is a PHP framework and therefore uses... PHP, which is a synchronous language. This implies a page refresh for every requests you make. The point is, every PHP framework have this behavior, this is the way PHP works.

So let's answer your question: indeed, you need an asynchronous technology to make a request to the server and get the response without refreshing the page. The technolodgy of choice in this case is Javascript, which will be able to make AJAX calls.

An AJAX (asynchronous JavaScript and XML) will, as stated in its name, make an asynchronous request. But an AJAX request is just the way of doing it, it's not really a technology. Yes, javascript frameworks like Vue.js are using AJAX, but that is overkill to just make some AJAX requests.

Using Axios or even jQuery is much easier and will allow you to make a request, grab the answer and modify your page without refresh very quickly :)

[EDIT]

The process to achieve what you are looking for is pretty simple:

1. Use Axios or jQuery to make an AJAX call (an asynchronous request)
2. Handle this request with Laravel, as you do for every other request
3. Returns something (or not, it depends of you) to alert your user that something happened
4. This response will be handled by Javascript

Comment: Is it possible to do some server side actions by jQuery such as deleting a record from a table? if so, you mean it is easier than AJAX?

Comment: It's not possible to "do" these actions with jQuery, since it is just a tool that allows you to easily send an AJAX request to the server. Laravel is the one that controls your database, it handles incoming requests and doesn't really care if they are sent through AJAX or a regular form (with page refresh). For Laravel, it's the same, if the request url matches a route, it'll go into it and Laravel will do it's business :)

Answer (score 0):

Vue is suitable for small projects where you just want to add a little bit of reactivity, submit a form with AJAX, show the user a modal, display the value of an input as the user is typing, or many other similarly straightforward things. It's scalable and also fantastic for huge project.